# Oracle simple update script causes "ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [15851], [6], [6], [1], [2], [], [], []"

Tags: sql, oracle, exception, oracle10g

I have this below query which has always worked successfully for years.

```
UPDATE t_fleet_net_exposure ne
SET avlimit = (SELECT avlimit FROM V_GROUP_CRLIM WHERE ca_id = ne.ca_id)
WHERE ne.ca_id IN (SELECT ca_id FROM V_GROUP_CRLIM);
```

This query is in a stored procedure which is triggered per 10 minutes by an Oracle Job. But recently this job failed and I have found that this update query is causing an error and not working.

Here is the error after I execute the script manually on Toad:

> ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [15851], [6], [6], [1],
>   [2], [], [], []

I couldn't find any proper reason when I googled it. People say it is Oracle's internal exception and I must open a TAR to Oracle Corporation. But I wonder if someone faced this error and could come up with a solution without raisin a TAR to Oracle.

Here is the steps that I already tried:

1. I created another table "t_fleet_net_exposure2" and populated with data from t_fleet_net_exposure. I thought, maybe the table's data is corrupted. But the update query caused ORA-600 again.
2. I created another view "V_GROUP_CRLIM2" and replaced with "V_GROUP_CRLIM" from the query. Maybe something was wrong with the view itself. But the update query end with ORA-600 again.
3. I created a temp table "TMP_V_GROUP_CRLIM" and populated with V_GROUP_CRLIM's result. Table and data created without any problem. So there is nothing wrong with the view.
4. I replaced the view V_GROUP_CRLIM with the newly created TMP_V_GROUP_CRLIM table from the update query, then update query worked fine. This is an acceptible workaround but now I have to truncate and re-fill the table every time I need to execute the update query. So I still need a proper reason/action to get rid of ORA-600 error.

My oracle server's version:

> Oracle Database 10g Release 10.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
>   PL/SQL Release 10.2.0.4.0 - Production                           CORE 
>   10.2.0.4.0    Production                                       TNS for 64-bit Windows: Version 10.2.0.4.0 - Production          NLSRTL
>   Version 10.2.0.4.0 - Production

Thanks in advance

Comment: These things depend on exact version (+ patches), instance parameters, sometimes even the OS you're running on. Unless you want to try some voodoo solutions, contact Oracle support. (They'll probably tell you to upgrade though.)

Comment: your core issue may be related to hash_area_size. Give a workaround by `alter session set hash_area_size = 1073741824` (1GB in this case as a sample size,  alter depending on your memory size) for the current session.

Comment: Increasing hash area size did not help, but thanks anyway!

Comment: you're welcome Hakan bey. Version 10 is very old, at least 11 should be preferred. I think your system is RAC. We also encountered such weird issues with RAC. Btw, nice to see worked in Başarsoft where I have friends formerly from ASKi (Ankara).

Comment: Thank you Barbaros bey, very nice to hear that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An ORA-600 is basically a bug, ie, a program crashed and hence we bailed out.

In your case, try this:

```
alter session set "_complex_view_merging" = false;
```

and see if that solves your problem.

The real solution here - upgrade to a supported version of the database :-)

Comment: Setting "_complex_view_merging" to "false" has solved the issue. What is the disadvantage to keep this value as "false"?

Comment: With each release of Oracle, the optimizer gets more enhancements in order to come up with new ways to run queries better. Complex view merging allows that, but you've hit a bug with it. You don't need to set it system wide, or you can even explore just using the NO_QUERY_TRANSFORMATION hint for that particular statement

Comment: Thanks @ConnorMcDonald, this worked in my case.